# How to create an AlertController mock in Ionic

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, ionic3

I am testing my Ionic 3 application with Jasmine, and I am wondering how to mock an `AlertController` that creates a confirmation alert.

The function that creates the confirmation alert is the following:

```
pressedButton:string="";
myAlert() {
    let confirm = this.alerCtrl.create({
        title: 'Title',
        message: 'Some message here',
        buttons: [
        {
            text: 'No',
            handler: () => {
                this.pressedButton = 'No';
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Yes',
            handler: () => {
                this.pressedButton = 'Yes';
            }
        }]
    });
    confirm.present()
}
```

Basically, what I want is to create a mock for the `AlertController` that simulates, for example, the user pressing the "yes" button so that I can test the code inside the Yes button handler. Following my unit test.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyPage);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('should set pressedButton to "Yes" when the user press the "Yes" button', () => {
    comp.myAlert(); //I want a mock that simulates the Yes button being pressed
    expect(comp.pressedButton).toEqual('Yes');
});
```

I have looked to ionic3-mocks (link below), but I can't figure out how to force button actions inside an alert.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic3-mocks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with ionic, but in the end, this is all just JavaScript and HTML. What you need to do is grab the DOM element corresponding to the button you want to click and then invoke the click method.

Here is what might work.

Add ids to all of your alert controller buttons, like this:

```
let confirm = this.alerCtrl.create({
    title: 'Title',
    message: 'Some message here',
    buttons: [
    {
        text: 'No',
        handler: () => {
            this.pressedButton = 'No';
        },
        id: 'no-alert'
    },
    {
        text: 'Yes',
        handler: () => {
            this.pressedButton = 'Yes';
        },
        id: 'yes-alert'
    }]
});
confirm.present()
```

Then in your test, grab the button element:

```
let yesButton = document.getElementById('yes-alert');
yesButton.click();
...continue the test...
```

---

**Update** It is better to test the controller itself and make sure that all the actions are wired up properly, but if that's not possible, you can just test the handler code directly.

Something like this would work:

```
export const yesHandler = () => ...
export const noHandler = () => ...

pressedButton:string="";
myAlert() {
    let confirm = this.alerCtrl.create({
        title: 'Title',
        message: 'Some message here',
        buttons: [
        {
            text: 'No',
            handler: noHandler
        },
        {
            text: 'Yes',
            handler: yesHandler
        }]
    });
    confirm.present()
}
```

And then you can test these handlers directly in your tests.

Comment: Your suggestion would work if I could use the original AlertController. However, when I tried to use the original controller I got the error stated in this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781394/cannot-read-property-getportal-of-undefined-in-ionic-2-unit-testing/40925405] This is why I need to create the mock

Comment: If you are not testing the actual controller, but just the code inside of the controller, why not call that code directly? I will update my answer.

Comment: Unable to add id inside buttons object

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with Ionic 4 (and previously, 3) and adding new mocks seems to be troublesome to me as well. With `AlertController`, you can find something useful at my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59193696/1594579.

Comment: This is not the answer , more like a comment.