# in Ionic v3 suddenly I am getting this error cannot read _getPortal from undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am getting this error in ionic v3 whenever I call a ModalController or an AlertController. It seems _appRoot is not defined. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '_getPortal' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '_getPortal' of undefined
    at App.present (app.js:241)
    at Alert.present (alert.js:101)
    at TaskDetailPage.<anonymous> (task-detail.ts:112)
```

Comment: Maybe related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781394/cannot-read-property-getportal-of-undefined-in-ionic-2-unit-testing

Comment: I had seen that but it was for unit testing which is not the environment I am in. But thanks anyway. It seems from what I can tell is that since I am using LazyLoading, the rootApp is undefined which is needed by Modal and Alert controllers. I am pretty sure it worked before so I am not sure if it is some type of regression or what

Comment: Hmm yeah not sure on this either... But I feel like I have seen this error before. Maybe this helps: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14785

Comment: Just found the problem. In one of my module I had imported CommonModule which didn't think could be a problem but removing it fixed it. Go figure. Thanks for your help

Comment: Did anyone figure out what is the reason behind this? I followed git hub link posted by @Phonolog , and it worked. Couldn't figure out the reason behind this too.. Any help??

Comment: I had multiple `IonicModule.forRoot` in my project, I removed all except one for `app-root` and it worked.